# How to pass input parameters to Liquid (Json) mapping ,this map will be used in Azure LogicApp

Tags: json, liquid, azure-logic-apps

Generally in XSLT mapping we can pass input parameter like (eg; <xsl:param name="input:templateID "/>),
Similarly is there any way that we can pass parameters for? .Liquid (Json) mapping?
Please let me know if there is any such...

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding/including the required parameter value into the source JSON using the Compose Action and then you can access that along with other parameters.
Here are couple of reference of liquid template for JSON transform:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform

https://rokhri.com/logic-app-using-liquid-template-to-transform-json/